# How to recover data from external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have external Hard drive, which shows the partition while view in disk manager. But I am not able to view the data stored on the hard drive. It is IMax 320 GB hard disk. Please help me.

Comment: for superuser...

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the drive is 320GB I would assume its using NTFS. I would highly recommend [**Recuva**](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) in this case, and if that fails, [**TestDisk**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) can do a more thorough job.

Answer (score 2):

Try [**Recuva**](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) from Piriform:

> Accidentally deleted an important
>   file? Lost something important when
>   your computer crashed? No problem!
>   Recuva recovers files deleted from
>   your Windows computer, Recycle Bin,
>   digital camera card, or MP3 player.
>   And it's free!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of wehre this question should be posted...

Don't do anything else... Just because you can't see the files, doens't mean that they're gone.

If your using a Windows PC, use [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,23069-order,1/description.html)

Answer (score 0):

Us something called [restoration](http://download.cnet.com/Restoration/3000-2094_4-10322949.html) (free) or a similar utility, and click scan for deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is on its last legs you could always try freezing it...
http://geeksaresexy.blogspot.com/2006/01/freeze-your-hard-drive-to-recover-data.html